# Converting BVP into standard Eigenfunction Eigenvalue form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

I have a eigen boundary value problem
$$
\lambda_h F''' - 2 \lambda_h \beta_h F'' + \left( (\lambda_h \beta_h - 1) \beta_h - \mu \right) F' + \beta_h^2F=0
$$
$\mu$ is the separation variable or the eigenvalue variable with b.c. as $F(0)=0,\frac{F''(0)}{F'(0)}=\beta_h,\frac{F''(1)}{F'(1)}=\beta_h$

Typically the eigenvalue and eigen function relation is shown as

$$
op(\bar{f})=\mu \bar{f}
$$
If the above relation is satisfied, then $\mu$ is called the eigenvalue of operator $op$ corresponding to eigen function $\bar{f}$

I am failing to express my EBVP in the standard form as my separation constant $\mu$ is attached to $F'$

**ATTEMPT**

$$
(\lambda_h\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-2\beta_h\lambda_h\frac{d}{dx}+{\beta_h}^2\int\mathbb{d}x)f=(-\lambda_h{\beta_h}^2+\beta_h+\mu)f
$$

assuming $F:=\int f(x)$

but then i cannot form a characteristic equation to go about finding eigenvalues

**NOTE**

I must make a note here that the solution $F$ or $f$ would be used in the following function

$$
\theta_w=e^{-\beta_hx}F'(x)e^{-\beta_cy}G'(y)$$ **or** 
$$\theta_w=e^{-\beta_hx}f(x)e^{-\beta_cy}g(y)$$

The initial EBVP gets complicated because it is third order and my described attempt makes it a Integro - Differential equation. Stuck at this for a while now.

***ATTEMPT 2***

Substituted $F=e^{kx}$ into the original EBVP yields

$$
e^{kx}(\lambda_h k^3- 2 \lambda_h \beta_h k^2 + \left( (\lambda_h \beta_h - 1) \beta_h - \mu \right) k + \beta_h^2)=0
$$
 So the characteristic polynomial is 
$$\lambda_h k^3- 2 \lambda_h \beta_h k^2 + \left( (\lambda_h \beta_h - 1) \beta_h - \mu \right) k + \beta_h^2=0$$

which can now have three roots

Comment: Do you have a typo? $\beta_h^2$ is a free variable in the original EBVP, but it is a prefactor for an integral operator in your attempt

Comment: Also, what exactly is the problem? Substitute $F = e^{kx}$ into the original equation, and you will have a 3rd order polynomial equation involving $k$ and $m$. Why does that not pass for a characteristic equation? It can be solved to express $k = K(m)$

Comment: @AleksejsFomins Yes,you were right. I had a typo in the original EBVP. Corrected it.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins The third order polynomial which i was getting without any substitution , just changed the problem  it into something like this $\lambda_h s^3 - 2 \lambda_h \beta_h s^2 + ((\lambda_h \beta_h - 1)\beta_h - \mu) s + {\beta_h}^2$. Solving for the three roots of it made it complicated

Comment: @AleksejsFomins From complicated i mean finding the eigenvalues without i.e. $\mu$ values. Also i do not complete grasp the logic where you mention $k=K(m)$

Comment: @AleksejsFomins I tried your substitution and edited the original question

Comment: I do not think that there is another way. If you want an analytical solution you need to be able to solve for the roots of the equation. If the analytical solution ends up being too messy, you might want to solve the equation numerically